# How do I add sequential access to my video stream?

Tags: .net, video, stream, httphandler, sequential

I'm streaming .flv videos from my SQL Server with the code below. But from what I understand the whole video will be loaded into memory before being played. What I would like to do is add CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess to the SQLDataReader... but I can't get it to work.

Please help me here. If you could provide a working example that is applicable to mine, I'd be happy. Psuedo code would be the second best alternative. Any pointers are appreciated though.

Here's my httpHandler

```
public class ViewFilm : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            // Check if video id was given
            if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
            {
                string video_ID = context.Request.QueryString["id"];

                // Connect to DB and get the video
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString))
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetVideo", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlParameter sqlParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@videoId", SqlDbType.Int);
                    sqlParam.Value = video_ID;

                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (dr.HasRows)
                        {
                            dr.Read();
                            // Add HTTP header: cache, content type and length
                            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
                            context.Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);
                            context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "video/x-flv");
                            context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", ((byte[])dr["data"]).Length.ToString());
                            context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["data"]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think streaming video from the DB is a good idea in the first place - rethink your design

Comment: Just got out of class and removed my comment. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: don't stream from the database.

Second: if you really WANT to stream from the database, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87z0hy49.aspx) is the example how you might do it.  But don't.  Really.  Store pointers (file paths) in the database and leave streaming handling to ISS or whatever server you use.